¿Se puede agregar 2 eventos onclick en un solo botón?
Buen Día.
El día de hoy quiero ejecutar dos eventos que llaman dos funciones de JS en un solo botón al ingresar un text de 4 caracteres, quisiera que en un solo input, al momento de ingresar los datos, solo un botón aplicara dos eventos. Por el momento los tengo separados.
<input  maxlength="4" id = "ingreso" type="text">
<button onclick="mostrarDatoDttoF(ingreso.value)">Consultar</button>


<input  maxlength="4" id = "ingreso1" type="text">
<button onclick="mostrarDatoDttoL(ingreso1.value)">Consultar</button>


Puedes crear una tercera función donde dentro de la misma ejecutas las 2 funciones pasándole el valor de ingreso e ingreso1 y así solo tienes 1 botón con la función creada:
JavaScript:
function nueva() {
    mostrarDatoDttoF(document.getElementById("ingreso").value);
    mostrarDatoDttoL(document.getElementById("ingreso1").value);
}

HTML:
<input  maxlength="4" id = "ingreso" type="text">
<input  maxlength="4" id = "ingreso1" type="text">
<button onclick="nueva()">Consultar</button> <!-- Se queda 1 botón solo -->



Sí es lo que me respondió @PyschoMX, nada más que hice unos ajustes a ese código.

La función que llama a las otras funciones también va declarada con el mismo evento que tiene el input.
function nueva() {
    mostrarDatoDttoF(document.getElementById("ingreso").value);
    mostrarDatoDttoL(document.getElementById("ingreso").value);
}

Y en HTML únicamente en el mismo input realiza los dos eventos de la función de JS.
<input  maxlength="4" id = "ingreso" type="text">
<button onclick="nueva(ingreso.value)">Consultar</button>

